# How to connect azure postgres with bastion?

Tags: azure, postgresql, bastion

In this [page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/quickstart-create-connect-server-vnet) also, it was shown to create a separate vm in the same vnet to connect to postgres setup in a private vnet option selected.

Is there anyway to connect using azure bastion.please show the steps.

Answer (score 1):

hi I found this article online that explains how to connect bastion server to PostgreSql via an ssh tunnel, I hope it can help you a lot in your intent, have a nice day :)

https://hackernoon.com/how-to-connect-your-bastion-server-to-a-postgresql-server-with-an-ssh-tunnel-pw3g35lt